# x11vnc: Ubuntu 14.04 unity desktop not responding to clicks

Tags: 14.04, xorg, vnc

I successfully installed x11vnc on Ubuntu desktop 14.04. I am able to access the shared screen but there is no mouse or keyboard interaction.

I created an upstart script to load x11vnc on startup using the following:

start on login-session-start

```
x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -repeat -display :0 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0 -forever -shared -bg -o /var/log/x11vnc.log -rfbauth /etc/x11vncpass -rfbport 5900 -dbg
```

Comment: The problem may be that the script starts too early. Try putting it in Startup Applications